# Error in Simple Cursor Adapter, not working

Tags: android

```
Cursor searchCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {"_id",Phone.DISPLAY_NAME}, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " like ?", 
        new String[]{ "%" + cc.get("contactName").toString() + "%"}, null);

startManagingCursor(searchCursor);
while(searchCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
    final String name = searchCursor.getString(searchCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    final String number = searchCursor.getString(searchCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
    str =new String[]{name,number};
    ada = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.view_contacts_listview_layout, searchCursor, str, new int[] { R.id.contactName, R.id.contactPhoneNo });
}

lvSearch.setAdapter(ada);
```

The cursor query running fine only getting problem in simple cursor adapter.

Comment: which error? or we just think...

Comment: Please describe _how_ it is not working and post any logcat errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str =new String[]{name,number};
```

should be

```
str = new String[]{Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};
```

You are supposed to pass the column names to the SimpleCursorAdapter. Instead, you are passing the column values (ex. 555-555-5555, "john") as the column names to use

Additionally, your code can be simplified to:

```
Cursor searchCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {"_id",Phone.DISPLAY_NAME}, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " like ?", 
                 new String[]{ "%" + cc.get("contactName").toString() + "%"}, null);

startManagingCursor(searchCursor);
str = new String[]{Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};
ada = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                R.layout.view_contacts_listview_layout, searchCursor,
                                str, new int[] {
                                        R.id.contactName, R.id.contactPhoneNo });
```

There's no reason to access your Cursor before sending it to the SimpleCursorAdapter. It will manage everything you need for you automatically.

I also noticed that you are also only selecting the contact _ID and DISPLAY_NAME in your query despite trying to access the NUMBER in your SimpleCursorAdapter.. you should modify your projection to include the phone number.. 
ex:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };

Cursor searchCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection , Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " like ?", 
                     new String[]{ "%" + cc.get("contactName").toString() + "%"}, null);
```

Comment: Thanks dymmeh, as i have not noticed this mistake.Now it's working fine, Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to help :) Mark it as the answer if you think it's the best solution

Comment: Sure dymmeh, but i don't know how to do this, as this was my first question that i have posted.

Comment: To the left of the answer there's a little empty checkbox. Just check that and it will turn green marking it as the answer :)